# &extend showing no matches when element exists

Tags: html, css, less

I am using less css for a basic website when i was trying to use `&extend` of less its showing no matches element when the element do exists.

I created a dummy environment same problem exists. Here is my code

**style.less**

```css
@import 'style1.less';
@colorgreen: #00ff00;
@colorred: #ff0000;
@fontsize: 20px;
@bsolid: solid;
@bdash: dashed;
 .container {
  border: 1px@bsolid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  .myclass {
    border: 1px@bdash #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    h1 {
      color: @colorred;

font-size: @fontsize;

    }
    p {
      color: @colorred;

font-size: @fontsize;

    }
  }
}
.extend {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  h2 {
    color: green
  }
  p {
    &: extend(h2);
    font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="myclass">
    <h1>Second Heading</h1>
    <p>LESS enables customizable, manageable and reusable style sheet for web site.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="importClass">
    <p>This is imported CSS.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="extend">
    <h2>First in extend</h2>
    <p>Second in extend</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code gives me no error when tried at http://less2css.org

Comment: agree but notice that i have used `&extend` after which the css `h2{color: green}` should be `h2,p{color: green}` but its not rendering like that

Comment: You should use the full selector and not just `h2`. It should be `.extend h2`.

Comment: thankyou so much...could you please tell me why it is so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the official [Less Website](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extending-nested-selectors) indicates, the Less compiler looks at the compiled CSS selector when processing `extend`.

> Essentially the extend looks at the compiled css, not the original less.

So, when trying to extend a nested selector, we should provide the full selector in the `extend` and not just the inner selector. In the example in question, the ***compiled CSS selector*** would be `.extend h2` and so when the `extend` statement has only `h2` provided as input, ***it wouldn't match*** and not output anything.

So, the below would compile successfully and work as per expectation.

```css
.extend{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  h2{
    color: green
  }
  p{
    &:extend(.extend h2);
    font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

When compiled, it would result in the below CSS:

```css
.extend {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.extend h2,
.extend p {
  color: green;
}
.extend p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```